# Errror when passing values from multiple DropDownLists to controller through ViewModel

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, viewmodel

I am trying to create a form DropDownLists created by **SelectList** that are generated based off the different [Bank] Accounts that a student user is associated with. So far I have been been able to successfully create two drop down lists for all of the accounts, but when I submit the form I get the error: **No parameterless constructor defined for this object.**

I am not really sure what the cause of this error is a I think I set up my controller and view correctly to handle the different values, but I am not sure if the ViewModel I pass in is correct.

**Account Model** (Bank account that is used in transfer ActionResult)

```
    public class Account
{
    [Key]
    [Editable(false)]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public virtual int AccountID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public virtual string AccountName { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]
    [Column(TypeName = "money")]
    public virtual decimal AccountTotal { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Student")]
    public virtual int StudentID { get; set; }

    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }

}
```

**TransferFundsViewModel** (This is the class that have my strongly-typed view built off of and I am trying to pass this to my controller.)

```
    public class TransferFundsViewModel
{
    public SelectList ListOfSourceAccounts { get; set; }
    public int SelectedSourceAccountId { get; set; }

    public SelectList ListOfDestinationAccounts { get; set; }
    public int SelectedDestinationAccountId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]
    public decimal TransferAmount { get; set; }
}
```

**TransferFunds Methods Inside my controller**

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult TransferFunds()
    {
        //Get logged in user
        var studentProfile = db.UserProfiles.Local.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name)
            ?? db.UserProfiles.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name);
        //Get student account associated with logged in user
        var student = db.Students.Find(studentProfile.UserId);
        //Get accounts associated with student account
        var accounts = db.Accounts.Where(x => x.StudentID == student.UserId);

        var selectionList = new SelectList(accounts, "AccountID", "AccountName");

        var vm = new TransferFundsViewModel { ListOfSourceAccounts = selectionList, ListOfDestinationAccounts = selectionList };

        return View(vm);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult TransferFunds(TransferFundsViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                AccountManager manager = new AccountManager();
                Account srcAccount = db.Accounts.Find(viewModel.SelectedSourceAccountId);
                Account destAccount = db.Accounts.Find(viewModel.SelectedDestinationAccountId);

                manager.TransferMoney(srcAccount, destAccount, viewModel.TransferAmount); //From Account Manager
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DataException)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Something went wrong, transfer could not be completed.");
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("AccountSummary");
    }
```

**AccountManager** (This is the class that holds the logic to actually transferring the funds.)

```
    public class AccountManager
{
    public void TransferMoney(Account srcAccount, Account destAccount, decimal transferAmount)
    {
        if (srcAccount.AccountTotal >= transferAmount)
        {
            srcAccount.AccountTotal -= transferAmount;
            destAccount.AccountTotal += transferAmount;
        }
    }
}
```

**Finally, the Transfer Funds View**

```
@model eBank.ViewModels.TransferFundsViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Transfer Funds</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            Source Account
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(viewModel => viewModel.ListOfSourceAccounts, Model.ListOfSourceAccounts, "Choose an Account")
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            Destination Account
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(viewModel => viewModel.ListOfDestinationAccounts, Model.ListOfDestinationAccounts, "Choose an Account")
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            Transfer Amount
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(viewModel => viewModel.TransferAmount)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Transfer" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the first parameter to use SelectedSourceAccountId when creating the dropdownlist.

Change

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(viewModel => viewModel.ListOfSourceAccounts, Model.ListOfSourceAccounts, "Choose an Account")
```

For

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(viewModel => viewModel.SelectedSourceAccountId, Model.ListOfSourceAccounts, "Choose an Account")
```

Same with the other Dropdownlist.

Now your model should have value on it and the srcAccount and destAccount objects won't be null.

Comment: Wow, that was really fast! Thank you. I can't believe that the fix was so simple... I spent at least an hour an a half experimenting with different solutions.